# How to respond to emails with information and promise to be contacted later

Tags: email

Example: I am currently doing an internship at a big company and its the first time in a work environment for me. After a students meeting where I talked with someone about possible contacts for further working possibilities I contacted the named person. He responded within a day, thanked me for my interest and stated there might be a possibility, but due to current absence would contact me later this week.

My question is: how and when to respond to such emails? For the moment I got the information I wanted and was not asked anything back. Do I have to thank for the time/information/...? Or is this leading to unnecessary email dump costing the other person valuable working time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just respond with

> Thanks, I look forward to hearing from you.

Then look forward to hearing from him.

There's no need for anything more complicated than this, and your response won't be a burden.